# Dirb error - "(!) FATAL: Too many errors connecting to host (Possible cause: RECV ERROR)"

Tags: linux, directory

I was trying to run Dirb on the url - http://testphp.vulnweb.com and I am getting an error.
What do I do?

*The error* -

````
└─$ dirb http://testphp.vulnweb.com/ /usr/share/wordlists/dirb/common.txt

-----------------
DIRB v2.22    
By The Dark Raver
-----------------

START_TIME: Tue Aug 23 01:40:29 2022
URL_BASE: http://testphp.vulnweb.com/
WORDLIST_FILES: /usr/share/wordlists/dirb/common.txt

-----------------

GENERATED WORDS: 4612                                                          

---- Scanning URL: http://testphp.vulnweb.com/ ----
                                                                                                                                                
(!) FATAL: Too many errors connecting to host
    (Possible cause: RECV ERROR)
                                                                               
-----------------
END_TIME: Tue Aug 23 01:41:49 2022
DOWNLOADED: 11 - FOUND: 0```
````

Answer (score 0):

I'd the same issue, but i solved it by typing dhclient in my virtual machine terminal

> dhclient